# Change "Remove" button text

Tags: entities

I'm trying to change the text from Remove button in my file and image fields.
For the field collection items I used this code.

```
function MY_MODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) 
{
  $element['actions']['remove_button']['#value'] = t('x');
}
```

It works fine. For file and image fields I tried this code.

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_file_widget_multiple(&$variables) {
  if( strcmp($variables['element']['#type'], 'details') == 0 ){
    $variables['element'][0]['remove_button']['#value'] = t('x');
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. With `MY_MODULE_field_widget_form_alter()` I can't get the *Remove* button.

Comment: Are you willing to edit it front end?

Comment: You mean using javascript? In general is something that i want to avoid but if I don't find a way I won't have any other option.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I can do it using javascript and CSS but I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was the [custom add another](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_add_another) module.

This is a very simple module that allows you to customise the text of the 'Add another item' button on multi-valued fields.

If your field supports 'unlimited' values then you are offered the option of customising the 'Add another item' button text. This setting is stored per 'bundle', so you can have different button text if you use the same field in two places.

UPDATE:

If you don't want to use unlimited upload you can just write your own module or add some piece of code in your custom module. (A big changed code from custom add another module)

In the hook_widget_form_alter:

```
$field = $context['items']->getFieldDefinition();
  if ($field instanceof FieldConfigInterface) {

    if (isset($element['remove_button']['#value'])) {
      $element['remove_button']['#value'] = t('x');
    }
    if (!empty($element['#type']) && $element['#type'] == 'managed_file') {
      $element['#process'][] = 'custom_file_buttons_labels';
    }
  }
```

And

```
function custom_file_buttons_labels($element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form) {

  if (isset($element['remove_button']['#value'])) {
    $element['remove_button']['#value'] = t('x');
  }
  return $element;
}
```